# Central limit theorem for weak correlated random variables

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, limit-theorems

I have a sequence of weak correlated continuous random variables $\{X_i\}$ with bounded variance and $\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)\rightarrow0$ for $|i-j|\rightarrow\infty$.

I was able to find a reference for the law of large numbers that work for above type of weakly correlated random variables.

I am trying to understand if there is a version of the central limit theorem that works for this kind of weakly correlated random variables.

I searched online and in one forum, I found that if covariance decays CLT works.
However, I am not able to find the correct reference or theorem.

[EDIt] Added that $X_i$'s are continuous random variables

Answer (score 7):

Even if the sequence $(X_i)$ is stationary with finite moments of any order and weakly dependent in every reasonable sense (so that, in particular, the condition $Cov(X_i,X_j)\to0$ as $|i-j|\to\infty$ holds), this is still not enough for any central limit theorem to hold.

E.g., for all integers $i$, let $X_i:=Y_i-Y_{i-1}$, where the $Y_i$'s are independent Rademacher random variables (r.v.'s), so that $P(Y_i=\pm1)=1/2$ for all $i$. Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=Y_n-Y_0,$$
which equals $Y_1-Y_0$ in distribution.
Here, instead of assuming that the $Y_i$'s are Rademacher r.v.'s, we may assume that the distribution of each $Y_i$ is any distribution (with finite moments of any order) that is not normal (and not degenerate), so that the distribution of $Y_1-Y_0$ be not normal (or degenerate).

This counterexample is given in the beginning of Ch. 18 of the book by [Ibragimov and Linnik](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Independent_and_stationary_sequences_of/TjdCSwAACAAJ?hl=en), where positive results are also given. See also some of the great many references to this book; MathSciNet counts over 600 such references.

In particular, see [Theorem 1.3 and Corollary 1.1 on p. 1339](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-28/issue-3/The-functional-central-limit-theorem-under-the-strong-mixing-condition/10.1214/aop/1019160337.full), stating a central limit theorem assuming certain moment and mixing conditions and, importantly, that $\liminf_n (Var\,\sum_1^n X_i)/n>0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the Reply. Will there be any possibility of CLT for continuous random variables with weak dependence.

Comment: @sar1729 : The continuity of the distribution will not help here. I have now added the corresponding detail to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming and updating the answer.
I am trying to understand the response in another question.
In the answer to the following thread, it was said that under certain conditions CLT holds when covariance decays. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20019/does-central-limit-theorem-hold-for-general-weakly-dependent-variables
Is it not applicable in case I mentioned in this question?

Comment: @sar1729 : In the answer that you linked in your latter comment, the important condition $Var\,\sum_1^n X_i\to\infty$ is missing. Also, I have now added a citation of an important positive result.

Comment: @sar1729 : Are you satisfied with the answer?

Comment: @losif Thank you very much for your replies. I am looking at https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701872 to figure out if it works for my problem